# Layout that can fill in remaining space and works when keyboard is open

Tags: android

[image]

I'm new to Android development. This is my desired layout.

The text box in the bottom should be high enought to contain its text. The send button has fixed size, but top align with the text box.

The top "Chat to" bar has fixed height. When I'm typing in the text box, ie. keyboard is open, the "Chat to" bar should still be visible.

The middle text view should take the remaining spaces.

I tried LinearLayout, when keyboard is open, the "Chat to" bar is not visible.

I brevity looked at RelativeLayout and ConstraintLayout but I'm still confused..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the AppBar, you can read more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/index.html).
You should move the content of your "Chat to" bar inside it